# UI In Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, user-interface

I have used Struts in my Web application , and Struts have its own UI tags to create a richer UI, Now I want to work with spring but I did,t find any UI Tag like Struts to create UI in Spring web application, Can any body suggest me how to create UI in spring as people used to create Spring Web application in IT Companies ?

Comment: Are you looking for http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib?

Comment: Yes something like this for creating UI in spring web application . Is it popular in IT Industry , and is any drawback using this ?

Comment: You can combine Spring with any web framework (Wiket, Vaadin, Angluar, Backbone, Play!...). But please do not use JSP :D

Comment: Thomas Uhrig : is it not enough Using "Spring's form tag library" to create UI in web application ?

Comment: Well, "enough" is a broad term. Of course you can create a web app like this. But other technologies maybe better. It depends on what you want to do. But JSP is an really old and odd technology (no matter what you want to do).

Comment: No My focus is not on JSP but I want to create UI like struts ui tag, So Please suggest me .

Comment: Take a look at Play!. It has wonderful template engine, where you write HTML template and fill them with Java objects.

Comment: For which template Engine you are talking, I have no idea about these . Please suggest which best suite with spring framework

Comment: @ThomasUhrig I use JSP all the time. Works very well for me I have to admit. If you're working with Spring I would suggest using it. It's the best supported view technology for the framework.